# Looping or not?

Tags: r, tidyverse, k-means

I would like to run `kmean()` in a data set. But I would like to set the second of argument in `kmean()` to `1:10`, that is I want to set the K from 1 to 10.

The data set generated from below code:

```
 data.frame( grps  = 1:5,
                           gsize = c(1000, 500, 750, 900, 800),
                           m1    = c(  -2,  -1,   0,   1,   2),
                           m2    = c(   0,   3,   1,   2,   4),
                           m3    = c(   1,   4,   2,   5,  -1),
                           m4    = c(   2,  -3,   4,  -1,   1) )

# training set generation
kd          <- centers        %>%
  group_by(grps) %>%
  do(data.frame( v1= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m1[1]),
                 v2= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m2[1]),
                 v3= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m3[1]),
                 v4= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m4[1])) )
```

```
minClusters <- 1
maxClusters <- 10

kclust  <- kd                                   %>%
  crossing(k= minClusters:maxClusters) %>%
  group_by(k)                          %>%
  do(clust= kmeans(select(., v1, v2, v3, v4), 
                   .$k[1], 
                   nstart=5) )
```

So I am confused whether the object `kclust` is gotten from looping? I think it is NOT, because the second argument in `kmeans()` function is a fixed number, "1". Maybe I misunderstand something?  Thank you!

Comment: It's giving `Error in eval_tidy(xs[[i]], unique_output) : 
  object 'minClusters' not found`.

Comment: `minClusters ==  1` , `maxClusters == 10`  @RuiBarradas

Comment: Thanks. I am not seeing anything wromg with your code, check out the difference between `kclust$clust[[1]]` and, say, `kclust$clust[[]]`. The result `kclust` is a tibble with  columns, `k` (number of clusters) and `clust` (objects of class `"kmeans"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works fine and the output is as expected. The issue is that since you are using random numbers to generate the data and the means are close by, the clusters are getting merged into 1 big cluster, hence most of the points are getting assigned to a single cluster. For example, you can check the 4th entry in the kclust$clust variable and you will see that there are 4 cluster centers, but right below that you will see that most points are assigned to cluster 1.

```
library(tidyverse)
centers = data.frame( grps  = 1:5,
        gsize = c(1000, 500, 750, 900, 800),
        m1    = c(  -2,  -1,   0,   1,   2),
        m2    = c(   0,   3,   1,   2,   4),
        m3    = c(   1,   4,   2,   5,  -1),
        m4    = c(   2,  -3,   4,  -1,   1) )

# training set generation
kd = centers %>%
  group_by(grps) %>%
  do(data.frame( v1= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m1[1]),
                 v2= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m2[1]),
                 v3= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m3[1]),
                 v4= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m4[1])) ) 

minClusters = 1
maxClusters = 10

kclust  <- kd %>%
  crossing(k = minClusters:maxClusters) %>%
  group_by(k) %>%
  do(clust = kmeans(select(., v1, v2, v3, v4), .$k[1], nstart=5))enter code here

> kclust$clust[4]
[[1]]
K-means clustering with 4 clusters of sizes 982, 771, 1399, 798

Cluster means:
          v1         v2         v3         v4
1 -2.0413678 0.01394798  0.9787409  1.9646186
2 -0.0179719 1.05571578  2.0228387  4.0233226
3  0.2979344 2.34438159  4.6230947 -1.6822656
4  1.9941418 4.03159297 -1.0617125  0.9776119

Clustering vector:
   [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  [69] 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [137] 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [205] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [273] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [341] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [409] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
 [477] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [545] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [613] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [681] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [749] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
 [817] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [885] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[953] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 1 1
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2950 entries ]
```

Try increasing the means to a larger range (* see UPDATE below) and results should be better. The other issue is that the data is ordered by the groups so it is also causing issues in the view when you only look at the 1st few samples (they should get assigned to the same cluster). Try shuffling the data points and the results would look more reasonable.

```
centers = data.frame( grps  = 1:5,
                      gsize = c(1000, 500, 750, 900, 800),
                      m1    = c(-10, -5, 0, 5, 10),
                      m2    = c(-10, -5, 0, 5, 10),
                      m3    = c(-10, -5, 0, 5, 10),
                      m4    = c(-10, -5, 0, 5, 10) )

# training set generation
kd = centers %>%
  group_by(grps) %>%
  do(data.frame( v1= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m1[1]),
                 v2= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m2[1]),
                 v3= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m3[1]),
                 v4= rnorm(.$gsize[1], .$m4[1])) ) %>%
  ungroup()

minClusters = 1
maxClusters = 10

kclust  <- kd %>%
  sample_frac(size=1) %>%
  crossing(k = minClusters:maxClusters) %>%
  group_by(k) %>%
  do(clust = kmeans(select(., v1, v2, v3, v4), .$k[1], nstart=5))


> kclust$clust[5]
[[1]]
K-means clustering with 5 clusters of sizes 900, 1000, 800, 750, 500

Cluster means:
             v1           v2          v3          v4
1   4.947859954  4.990537346  4.96409669  5.02513562
2 -10.014275191 -9.990181395 -9.96969088 -9.96127717
3  10.054780835  9.942738199 10.03617191 10.01820661
4   0.005084275 -0.003034476 -0.03353889 -0.01343343
5  -5.056184108 -5.004413465 -5.00059546 -5.06765925

Clustering vector:
   [1] 2 4 4 2 4 2 4 1 4 4 5 4 1 3 1 3 1 1 2 2 2 2 4 2 4 5 2 4 2 2 4 3 2 1 3 1 2 2 3 4 1 4 1 3 3 5 2 3 3 1 1 4 5 2 4 2 4 2 2 2 2 5 3 2 5 2 1 5
  [69] 2 3 1 1 1 2 2 1 4 2 1 1 2 2 4 4 2 2 5 5 4 2 3 4 5 2 5 3 5 5 4 3 3 3 1 3 5 3 4 1 3 4 1 2 2 3 4 1 1 3 3 1 2 3 5 2 3 1 2 3 5 3 2 2 2 2 1 4
 [137] 4 3 1 4 5 2 3 1 4 1 3 3 1 2 3 3 1 3 1 4 4 2 1 1 5 3 3 2 4 3 5 3 1 3 1 4 4 2 1 3 1 2 3 5 2 1 3 1 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 2 5 2 3 3 1 5 3 2
 [205] 5 3 2 2 3 5 2 4 5 4 1 1 2 2 3 1 4 2 4 1 5 3 3 3 5 4 1 2 3 3 5 1 1 5 1 3 3 2 2 5 3 2 2 1 2 4 2 5 4 5 5 2 4 5 3 4 5 3 1 1 2 1 1 2 4 2 4 1
 [273] 2 3 4 5 2 3 1 5 3 3 3 3 5 4 3 4 2 3 2 4 1 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 2 2 3 5 4 5 2 1 4 2 1 3 2 3 4 4 2 2 2 4 3 3 1 4 1 3 5 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 4 1 2 4 2 3
 [341] 2 3 3 2 3 1 5 3 2 5 2 3 4 4 1 2 5 3 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 4 1 2 3 5 4 1 4 3 4 3 4 1 4 5 5 5 4 2 4 3 1 2 3 2 3 1 3 2 4 5 4 2 1 1 1
 [409] 4 1 5 2 4 2 1 2 3 4 3 4 5 2 3 5 2 3 1 4 1 1 4 3 3 1 1 1 3 2 2 5 1 3 2 2 2 5 4 4 5 4 1 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 5 1 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 3 2 3 4
 [477] 2 3 4 2 5 2 4 2 3 1 5 4 3 4 3 3 2 4 3 3 5 2 5 4 4 1 1 2 3 1 5 4 3 1 2 5 2 2 4 2 3 3 2 4 1 3 5 2 1 3 5 5 2 1 3 1 1 5 5 2 1 5 3 2 2 3 3 2
 [545] 2 1 4 4 4 1 2 1 5 5 2 1 4 3 3 2 5 5 2 4 3 2 4 1 3 3 1 3 4 3 2 4 2 5 4 4 3 1 4 5 4 2 1 4 4 2 3 1 2 2 2 4 1 2 2 1 5 5 2 2 4 4 1 5 4 4 4 4
 [613] 2 3 3 1 1 3 3 1 4 4 5 1 2 1 1 4 3 2 5 4 2 5 3 3 3 1 4 1 2 3 5 2 2 4 4 5 2 3 3 1 3 4 3 5 2 2 2 2 4 3 3 2 3 2 4 3 2 2 1 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 3 1
 [681] 3 2 2 5 4 2 4 4 5 2 1 3 1 2 4 1 3 3 4 1 4 4 3 2 2 4 4 3 5 4 1 1 5 2 2 3 5 4 1 1 4 2 5 3 3 1 2 1 2 4 4 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 1 4 1 1 1 4 3 2 3 5
 [749] 1 4 4 3 4 4 4 2 4 2 3 3 1 1 1 4 2 3 1 4 1 4 3 2 3 2 2 4 1 5 1 4 2 4 2 2 1 4 3 4 5 2 3 4 4 2 2 1 5 1 2 1 2 1 1 5 1 5 2 4 1 2 1 2 2 3 1 4
 [817] 5 1 4 2 4 4 4 5 3 2 1 4 1 3 4 2 1 5 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 2 1 4 1 4 5 1 2 5 3 5 4 1 4 1 4 1 3 2 4 3 1 3 5 4 3 1 5 4 3 2 4 3 3 4 4 3 5 4 2 4 2 1
 [885] 1 1 4 2 4 5 1 2 5 4 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 4 1 5 4 2 2 2 4 1 4 3 4 1 2 4 2 1 4 3 5 1 1 5 5 4 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 2 1 1 1 1 3 2 4 1 1 4 2 5 2
 [953] 3 4 5 2 5 4 1 3 5 2 4 3 4 4 2 4 2 4 1 1 1 1 2 2 4 1 1 3 2 4 3 1 5 1 2 5 4 2 3 2 3 1 2 1 2 1 5 4
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2950 entries ]
```

UPDATE:

And, I verified that the real issue is the second one (i.e. your data is ordered). You don't need to change the means. You can use the same means (as your original code) and as long as you shuffle the data, you should see the points assigned to multiple clusters.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The key is I don not quite understand how the object kclust() was generated. So you mean, the `kclust ` is generated by some data manipulation which is same as looping?  Or I should ask, the code in kclust() object, equals I run kmeans() 10 times separately?  Specifically, if I set `.$k[1]` to `.$k[2]`, what happened? I think .$k[1] is a fixed number, right?

Comment: You are grouping by K right before clustering and since you have 10 values for k from 1 to 10, the clustering operation will be applied on each of those 10 groups individually (so similar to looping). So the first group will use a k value of 1 (and clustering will use this k value), the second group will use a k value of 2 (and clustering will use this k value) and so on.

Comment: If you are new to dplyr, the syntax can be a bit confusing. I would recommend that you try to run the code by adding one line at a time to see how dplyr is working at each step and that will make it easier to understand what the code is doing. Feel free to post back if you have more questions and I will be happy to elaborate.

Comment: Now I understand how the data set was grouped and generated. Last question, in `do(clust = kmeans(select(., v1, v2, v3, v4), .$k[1], nstart=5))` , the second argument in `kmeans()`, which is `.$k[1]`, I know `.k$` means the named column `k` of the grouped dataset, but in here what is meaning of `[1]`?  Is it only syntax requirement or it has actually meaning? If I change `[1]` to other number, what is the difference?  Thank you!

Comment: I believe that you are accessing the K th column using .$k, but for the argument to KMean, you only need to pass a single value of K. Since all the group values will have the same K value, the author of the code is just picking the 1st value using .k[1]. This is the safest option, though .k[2] will also work as long as you have 2 rows in that group. The reason I said k[1] is the safest option is that you know there will at least be 1 row but are not guaranteed to have 2 rows in the group. Hope that helps!